# How Netty ChannelFuture notify does not cause dead lock

Tags: java, netty, future

I've read Netty Guide, it does not explain much on `ChannelFuture`. I am confused why It won't cause a deadlock.

1.It teaches me to start up a server like this.

```
ServerBootstrap sb = new ServerBootstrap();
        sb.group(bossGroup, workerGroup);
        sb.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        sb.localAddress(new InetSocketAddress(port));
        sb.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {

                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(new BigGameMessageDecoder(msgRegistry));
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(BIG_MSG_ENCODER);
                    if (isDebug) {
                        ch.pipeline().addLast(MSG_LOGGER);
                    }

                    ch.pipeline().addLast(new GameMessageHandler<>(msgRegistry,
                            sessionFactory.createGameSession(), event, false));
                } 

        });

        ChannelFuture cf = sb.bind().sync();
        logger.error("start server at port: {}", port);
        if (sync) {
            cf.channel().closeFuture().sync();
        }
```

In line:

```
ChannelFuture cf = sb.bind().sync();
```

`sb.bind()` returns a `ChannelFuture` and `sync()` will wait until this future isDone.

I read `DefaultChannelGroupFuture` code, it shows me to `sync()` calls `await()` indeed.
And `await()` lock itself, wait for other's notify.

And in `ChannelFuture`'s function `setSuccess` it tries to get that lock again. So my question is if `sync()` gets the lock first then waits and then `ChannelFuture` tries to notify but it can not get the lock. Will it cause a deadlock?

2. If don't, how can `ChannelFuture` notify other listeners?
3. Other books told me DO NOT USE `sync()` or `await()` in `ChannelHandler` because It may cause deadlock. Why? What's the difference between Question 1 and 3?

---

```
public DefaultChannelGroupFuture sync() throws InterruptedException {
    super.sync();
    return this;
}

  public Promise<V> sync() throws InterruptedException {
    await();
    rethrowIfFailed();
    return this;
}


  public Promise<V> await() throws InterruptedException {
    if (isDone()) {
        return this;
    }

    if (Thread.interrupted()) {
        throw new InterruptedException(toString());
    }

    synchronized (this) {
        while (!isDone()) {
            checkDeadLock();
            incWaiters();
            try {
                wait();
            } finally {`enter code here`
                decWaiters();
            }
        }
    }
    return this;
}

  public Promise<V> setSuccess(V result) {
    if (setSuccess0(result)) {
        notifyListeners();
        return this;
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("complete already: " + this);
}



  private boolean setSuccess0(V result) {
    if (isDone()) {
        return false;
    }

    synchronized (this) {
        // Allow only once.
        if (isDone()) {
            return false;
        }
        if (result == null) {
            this.result = SUCCESS;
        } else {
            this.result = result;
        }
        if (hasWaiters()) {
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your above code:

```
public Promise<V> await() throws InterruptedException {
if (isDone()) {
    return this;
}

if (Thread.interrupted()) {
    throw new InterruptedException(toString());
}

synchronized (this) {
    while (!isDone()) {
        checkDeadLock();
        incWaiters();
        try {
            wait();
        } finally {`enter code here`
            decWaiters();
        }
    }
}
return this;
```

The `sync` method code `checkDeadLock();` will check current thread is not internal thread which is used to deal io event,if not ,the deadlock will occur while the bind operation will dispatch to the same thread that wait for the lock.And then,the `wait();` will release the lock of `this` and wait for some thread acquire the lock and notify it.When the IO thread call the `setSuccess`,it can acquire the lock,because no one hold the lock.

Comment: So if in my channelHandler method `channelInactive` try to reconnect sync like this `bootstrap.connect().sync();`   The `bootstrap` is the strap to connect the server. By our conclusion above,it will throw an exception by certain. But actually, occurrence of exception is fortuitous.
`io.netty.util.concurrent.BlockingOperationException: DefaultChannelPromise@3b72750a(incomplete)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultPromise.java:380) ~[netty-all-4.0.13.Final.jar:4.0.13.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.checkDeadLock(DefaultChann`

Comment: @user8119590 because of the awai() not wait lock when the operation has been completed.you can execute the code `bootstrap.connect().channel().closeFuture().sync()`,and see what happened.

Comment: I got it. It depends on whether `bootstrap.connect()`'s future respond fast or not. When executing `sync()` if `isDone()` return `true`  method will return , so there is no Exception. And if `isDone()` return `false` then method will check the deadlock.  @dabaicai

Comment: @wangcaicai That's right,the isDone() is key method.